# Http Outbound Gateway Sending Json request from pojo payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to send a simple POST request to a REST endpoint. I have a simple pojo that I would like to send in the payload as JSON. Here is the pojo (note I'm using Spring Integration with grails so the pojo/service are in Groovy):

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    String name
}
```

Here is my gateway:

```
public interface PersonGateway {
    Person savePerson(Person person)
}
```

Here are the important parts of the wiring:

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="responseChannel" />
<int:header-enricher input-channel="requestChannel">
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:gateway id="PersonGateway"
             service-interface="com.example.PersonGateway"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel"
             default-reply-channel="responseChannel">
    <int:method name="savePerson" />
</int:gateway>
<int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/person"
                           http-method="POST"
                           message-converters="jsonConverter"
                           expected-response-type="com.example.Person"
                           request-channel="requestChannel"
                           extract-request-payload="false"/>
```

This POST request never reaches that service but doesn't throw any exceptions. When I log all levels the only thing I get that looks like a clue is:

> 2014-03-30 16:35:07,313 [main] DEBUG
>   outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler  - Unable to attempt
>   conversion of Message payload types. Component
>   'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0'
>   has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no
>   'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.

Other than that it doesn't give me much. I've been trying little things all day and can't seem to get anywhere. Anyone see what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: You are expecting a `Person` response. What is your request payload type? You are setting the content type to JSON; do you have Jackson on the classpath?

Comment: The payload should be of type `Person` as well. I do have Jackson in my path.

Comment: Additional data point: I see a similar result.  I am not the extract-request-payload, nor a message converter.  If the header in the enricher is present, the gateway does a "loopback", returning the string parameter value I am sending it and not sending the request out.  Removing the header element causes the request to be delivered to the remote service.  I'm not sure I understand how this loopback behavior is correct.  To be precise, I have "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.4" in my classpath;, not sure if this is what is meant by "having Jackson in the class path".

Answer (score 0):

1. `Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types.`
   Don't worry: it doesn't have value for you. In most cases we can live in our application without that `integrationConversionService`. Here it is needed for expressions. Since you don't use any expression, that WARN doesn't hurt you.
2. You say that you are going to send POJO as JSON, then you shouldn't use `extract-request-payload="false"`. With `false` the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` places to the request body entire `Message<?>` and changes `content-type` to `application/x-java-serialized-object`
3. Hope your `jsonConverter`does the correct stuff around POJO <-> JSON

Comment: Unfortunately setting `extract-request-payload="true"` didn't make any difference. I've been tinkering with different settings like this and it is discouraging that I don't get any helpful errors.